# OutOfMemoryError when inflating a layout

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I keep seeing this out of memory error in my developer console and I do not know why

log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:421)
at ecm2.android.MessageDialog.PopUpMessage(MessageDialog.java:90)
at ecm2.android.MainActivity.PopMessage(MainActivity.java:1830)
at ecm2.android.MainActivity$10.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:1355)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at android.widget.ScrollView.setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.java:1404)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1879)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1921)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:292)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:88)
at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:145)
at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:141)
```

this is my layout XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"              
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="2dip" android:paddingTop="2dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout2" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:padding="0dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="fill_parent">   

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:contentDescription="@string/desc">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/txtDialogHeader" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:textColor="#ff2525" android:textSize="18dip">
        </TextView>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/txtDialogTOC" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDialogHeader"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:textSize="19dip" android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView    
        android:id="@+id/scrollMessageFrame"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:background="#AA0000"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:text="" 
            android:id="@+id/lblMessage"  
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:minHeight="140dip" android:textColor="#f2f2f2" android:textSize="20dip">
        </TextView>

    </ScrollView> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout3" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cmdResponding"
            android:layout_width="62dip"
            android:layout_height="62dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:src="@drawable/responding_ref" android:background="@drawable/responding_up" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip">
</ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/cmdDeclining" android:src="@drawable/declining_ref" android:background="@drawable/declining_up" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cmdResponding" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cmdResponding" android:layout_height="62dip" android:layout_width="62dip" android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmdResponding" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cmdChiefList"
            android:layout_width="62dip"
            android:layout_height="62dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmdDeclining" android:background="@drawable/chief_up" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:src="@drawable/chief_ref" android:contentDescription="@string/desc" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/cmdMapping" android:background="@drawable/globe_up" android:src="@drawable/mapping_ref" android:layout_height="60dip" android:layout_width="60dip" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cmdChiefList" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"></ImageButton>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<Button 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:layout_width="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/cmdExit" 
    android:background="@drawable/closepopup"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:contentDescription="@string/desc">
</Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

the line where the error is, is at the `setContentView(r.layout.mylayout)`. there are no big images in this layout, most are small `imagebuttons` 6 images in total `(biggest image is 90x90)` and a bunch of text in a `scrollview`. so how can I get around this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using the layout file without the images? How much is `a bunch of text`?

Comment: @tyczj : Is there a reason you are putting a `TextView` in a `ScrollView`? It seems unnecessary as `TextView` can handle its own scrolling.

Comment: This is exactly my logcat. And what is the main problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bunch of text in a scrollview" will generate a huge image even if only a small fraction of the text is visible at a time, thanks to the scrollview.

Try to determine which part of the text is going to be visible, and process only that.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout looks complicated.  Try replacing all the different kinds of layouts with just one `RelativeLayout`.